# Table starts on line 1 not on line 0

Tags: c

The function searches the longest/shortest string in a table. I can code and read it but as soon as I enter the function `void minmax(char *ptab, char **pva, int n)` it jumps to line 1 instead of going to line 0. Therefore, the very first `line[0]` is never read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int encodage(char [][50]);
void affichage(char [][50],int);
void minmax (char *,char **,int);

int main()
{   
    char tab[50][50];
    char *va[2];
    int n;
    n=encodage(tab);
    affichage(tab,n);
    minmax(&tab[0][50],va,n-1);
    printf("\nTest\n");
    puts(*va);
    fflush(stdin);
    puts(*(va+1));
    return 0;
}

//Code and Read the table with the encodage and affichage.

void minmax(char *ptab,char **pva,int n)
{
    int i;
    *pva=ptab;
    *(pva+1)=ptab;
    ptab=ptab+50;
    for(i=1;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(strlen(ptab)>strlen(*(pva+1)))
        {
            *(pva+1)=ptab;
        }
        else
        {
            if(strlen(ptab)<strlen(*(pva)))
            {
                *(pva)=ptab;
            }
        }
        ptab=ptab+50;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tab[0][50] means the element with index 50 in tab[0], not tab[0] itself. Apart from this is index 50 out of bounds. If you like tor print a string use `printf("%s", ... );`

```
void minmax (char[][50] ,char **,int);

int main()
{
    char tab[50][50];
    char *va[2];
    int n = encodage( tab );
    affichage( tab, n );
    minmax( tab, va, n ); // <-
    printf( "short %s\n", va[0] );
    printf( "long  %s\n", va[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

If you like to find the shortest and the longest string proceed as follows:

Your first parameter ist a pointer to the tabel of the strings. The second one is a pointer to  the both result strings and the third is the number of strings in your table (Not `n-1` or somthing else).

```
void minmax(char ptab[][50], char **pva, int n )
              //     ^^^^^^
{
    int i, len0, len1, len;
    pva[0]=ptab[0];              // init shortest string with pointer to first string in table
    pva[1]=ptab[0];              // init longest string with pointer to first string in
    len0 = strlen( pva[0] );     // remember lenght of shortest string
    len1 = len0;                 // remember lenght of longest string
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)             // iterate from secend string up to last string (1..49 in your case)
    {
        len = strlen( ptab[i] ); // get length of string with index i
        if( len > len1 )         // if lenght is greater than lenght of longest string, then this is longest string
        {
            len1 = len;          // remember new maximum lenght
            pva[1]=ptab[i];      // remember new maximum string
        }
        else if( len < len0 )    // if lenght is less than lenght of shortest string, then this is shortest string
        {
            len0 = len;          // remember new minimum length
            pva[0]=ptab[i];      // remember new minimum string
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still give me the warning:
Line 19:
warning: passing argument 1 of 'minmax' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Line 6:
note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[50]'